# FFmpeg avcodec_send_packet выдает ошибку -1094995529

Tags: c++, видео, потоки-данных, ffmpeg

Пытаюсь из sdp файла получить видео. Но так как впервые работаю с FFmpeg не могу понять, что я делаю не правильно.

Данный sdp файл открывается в VLC без каких либо проблем. Команда
`ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i ./stream.sdp` также запускает стрим без нареканий.

stream.sdp

```
v=0
o=- 1360349812962 1360349812962 IN IP4 169.254.0.45
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 169.254.0.45
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 17884 RTP/AVP 96
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42c01e;sprop-parameter sets=Z0LAHukBQHsg,aM4G4g==;
```

Основные фрагменты кода, связанные с функциями ffmpeg (Опустил необязательные проверки)

```
AVFormatContext *format_context = avformat_alloc_context();

AVDictionary* opt = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&opt,"buffer_size","6553600",0);
av_dict_set(&opt,"protocol_whitelist","file,udp,rtp",0);

AVInputFormat* format = av_find_input_format("sdp");
int err = avformat_open_input(&format_context, fileName, format, &opt);

err = avformat_find_stream_info(format_context, nullptr);

int ret = av_find_best_stream(format_context, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &codec, 0);

uint video_stream = ret




err = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, nullptr);

AVPacket packet;

int ret = av_read_frame(format_context, &packet);
if (ret >= 0)    {
        if (decodeHWenable){

            DecodeFrameHW(&packet);
        }
}
```

Функция DecodeFrameHW, в которой возникает проблема (avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet) возвращает -1094995529)

```
void Decoder::DecodeFrameHW(AVPacket* packet){



    if (static_cast<uint>(packet->stream_index) == video_stream) 
    {

        int ret = avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet);
                   ...
     }
}
```

Хотелось бы понять, что значит -1094995529, почему возникает такая ошибка и как это можно исправить

Comment: GetLastError + SysErrorMessage что-нибудь показывают?
Или можно попробовать сравнить значение с константами по информации отсюда - https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga58bc4bf1e0ac59e27362597e467efff3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка исчезла при добавлении строчки `codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(dhwElem.codec);`

```
AVFormatContext *format_context = avformat_alloc_context();

AVDictionary* opt = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&opt,"buffer_size","6553600",0);
av_dict_set(&opt,"protocol_whitelist","file,udp,rtp",0);

AVInputFormat* format = av_find_input_format("sdp");
int err = avformat_open_input(&format_context, fileName, format, &opt);

err = avformat_find_stream_info(format_context, nullptr);

int ret = av_find_best_stream(format_context, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &codec, 0);

uint video_stream = ret


codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(dhwElem.codec);

err = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, nullptr);

AVPacket packet;

int ret = av_read_frame(format_context, &packet);
if (ret >= 0)    {
        if (decodeHWenable){

            DecodeFrameHW(&packet);
        }
}
```